# Problem with SQL statement using EXISTS, ALL, ANY

Tags: sql, database, exists, any

I have to find the names of all the Providers which have in Catalog all the auto parts that provider with `id = 101` has, using `EXISTS` or `ALL` or `ANY`.

`Providers` is the first table which contains `id` and `nameProvider`.
`Catalog` is the second table which contains `id` and `idp` (id of auto parts)

Query:

```
select nameProvider
from Providers
where id in (select id from Catalog where id = 101);
```

What's missing from my statement? Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use EXISTS, ALL or ANY? I'd go with EXISTS here, and a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 0):

- Using minus operator in the corraleted subquery, and with not exists would work fine
- I filter out id = 101 as I assume that Provider id =101 is not needed in the ouput

```sql
select nameProvider
from Providers p
where p.id != 101
and not exists ( 
  select  idp from Catalog c1 where c1.id = 101 
    minus 
  select  idp from Catalog c2 where c2.id = p.id
  )
;
```